# Sonar and C#: Download of guava-10.0.1.jar fails due to timeout

Tags: sonarqube

we have Sonar set up to run on a separate server. It does, and a client application (sonar-runner) can connect successfully to it. However, the run interrupts with the following exception:

```
Runner configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-runner-1.3\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
Project configuration file: C:\project\subproject\sonar-project.properties
Runner version: 1.3
Java version: 1.6.0_33, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS name: "Windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86"
Server: http://<serverip>:80
Work directory: C:\project\subproject\.sonar
Total time: 1:30.902s
Final Memory: 0M/15M
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://<serverip>:80/batch/guava-10.0.1.jar
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:164)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.createClassLoader(Runner.java:155)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:78)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://<serverip>:80/batch/guava-10.0.1.jar
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:113)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:159)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)

        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapperIOUtils.copyLarge(BootstrapperIOUtils.java:63)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContentToFile(Bootstrapper.java:109)
        ... 5 more
```

I can reproduce this with a normal browser. Retrieving the file opens the download manager, however, it takes up to 5 minutes until the file finally downloads (it's only 1.5 megs). Other files that are retrieved by the sonar-runner or using a browser do not have this problem.

The sonar logging doesn't seem to know that there is a problem. Downloads are not logged in the sonar.log file, neither successful ones nor the unsuccessful one. syslog doesn't contain any hints to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was not something on the server, but rather a client-side problem. Kaspersky Endpoint Security seems to have a bug/feature that it needs to scan everything going over the network, and somehow this one JAR file triggered a multiple-minute-long delay while the file was being scanned.

Answer (score 4):

had similar problem with sonar+php plugin and eset smart security. Had to disable filtering on 127.0.0.1 in filtering protocols section. It was happening randomly on different jars. It was happening on both solar ant task and solar runner